# Mule - Parse CSV to ArrayList of hash maps based on CSV header values

Tags: java, csv, arraylist, hashmap, mule

I have a simple csv

`TYPE,DATE,NAME
 SERIAL,20170808,TR
NUEROUS,20160608,WB`

This is my flow for converting csv to arraylist of hashmaps(currently using indexes)

```
<set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="text/csv" 
mimeType="application/csv" doc:name="Property"/>

  <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
    <dw:input-payload doc:sample="sample_data/string.dwl" mimeType="application/csv"/>

      <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
payload map ((payload , indexOfPayload) -> {
operationType:payload[0],
issueDate:payload[1],
issueNumber:payload[2]
})]]></dw:set-payload>
         </dw:transform-message>
```

Thing is that currently i am using indexes, but what when header csv indexes will be changed? so i need to do the parsing based on csv header names. e.g

```
operationType: payload.TYPE
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using header column name as the key for getting value.

```
<dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:input-payload mimeType="application/csv"/>
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
payload map ((payload , indexOfPayload) -> {
operationType:payload.TYPE,
issueDate:payload.DATE,
issueNumber:payload.NAME
})]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
```

As per [Mule documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-formats#reader-properties)

> When header=true you can then access the fields within the input anywhere by name. Ex: payload.userName.
>
> When header=false you must access the fields by index, referencing first the entry and then the field, Ex: payload[107][2]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've put the header into `<dw:reader-property name="header" value="true"/>` and it works ! Many thanks to you